# Calculating Percentile

Tags: probability, statistics

so I'm doing my Stats Module, and I'm sort of stuck on this question, I don't know if I'm over thinking it because finding the standard deviation and whatnot was fairly simple but anyways, here's the data set, and they want me to find the percentile for 87.13:

{86.04, 86.14, 87.13, 89.87, 91.03, 92.15, 93.31, 98.59, 105.05, 105.95, 106.6, 107.79, 108.08, 108.54}

I'd appreciate if you could explain how you found the percentile in the most simple way possible for my understanding, I hate stats and I'm required to take this course for my major

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give the desired answer, you are going to have to look at what you have been taught, as there are different approaches.

$87.13$ is the 3rd smallest term of the 14 values you have.

So $\frac{2}{14} \approx 14.3\%$ of the data is below $87.13$, and  $\frac{3}{14} \approx 21.4\%$  is less than or equal to $87.13$.  The answer desired will be one of these or some value in between them.

Comment: Yes, the answer I was given was 14.29, I just needed an understanding of it, so thank you very much for that!